# Linux UDP short broadcast with longer response expected

Tags: linux

The receiving platform is Linux-2.6.37_DM8127_IPNC_3.80.00 (TI's DaVinci processor).
In the course of a discovery process, I make a short broadcast (Win7) - the expected response to which is several bytes longer than the length of the broadcast.

I always get a partial response - having exactly the length of the broadcast. This happens regardless of the computer, firewall being on/off, antivirus etc.

Padding the broadcast to the length of the expected response - and I get the desired response.

Is this some LINUX feature - or should I keep on searching for some bug in my code?

Comment: It's a bug in your code. There's nothing that automatically assumes any relationship between the size of a message you send and the response you receive.

Comment: Not a LINUX problem! Analyzing the scenario using Wireshark, it is evident that the 9 byte UDP broadcast, made by the WIN32 C host running on WIN7, elicited the expected 16 byte response from the LINUX client. However, only receives 9 bytes are recvfrom'ed by the host...

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the receiving code in the application. It's not giving a large enough buffer size when it calls `recv()`, it's using the same size that it wrote.

Comment: No - that's not the case - buffer size is 64 > 16... Looks to me like some Windows security tactic to beef up security for UDP tunneling. After successfully tunneling through, each non-broadcast request of any size gets any number of bytes in response...

Comment: That makes very little sense. There are few UDP-based protocols where the replies are no bigger than the requests. In fact, it's a very unlikely scenari (think of DNS as an example -- the request just contains the name, the replies contain lots of information about the name).